# Can't update DiG utility on Debian 8 (Jessie)

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, update, debian-jessie, dig

I am trying to get the latest version of DiG DNS utility (part of BIND 9) but I can't seem to be able to.

I am running Debian 8 (Jessie).
The current DiG version :

```
root@myMachine:~# dig -v
DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u14-Debian
```

I want to get the version that comes with Debian 9:

```
root@secMachine:~# dig -v
DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian
```

I tried update commands for BIND and dnsutils, but no use.

```
root@myMachine:~# apt-get install -y dnsutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
dnsutils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 118 not upgraded.

root@DXB-RYH-EPROBE12:~# apt-get install -y bind9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
bind9 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 117 not upgraded.
```

How can update DiG to v9.10 or to the latest version, without upgrading to Debian 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

There is a reason why there are releases of distributions; the `dnsutils` package (which contains the `dig` command) will depend on other packages supplying shared libraries, and those in turn will also need newer versions of other things, potentially leading to "dependency hell".

For certain packages a "backport" version can be available especially for this situation, which is made by taking the source package from the newer release and building it on the older release. In this manner the resulting binaries are happy with the versions of shared libraries in the older release. Check what's available by visiting https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dnsutils. This shows that for Jessie there is [knot-dnsutils](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/knot-dnsutils) available. Download that via the links on that page and install that by hand:

```
dpkg -i knot-dnsutils_2.3.2-1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb
```

If you regularly want to use backported packages, then you could add this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

After doing that you can use `apt` / `apt-get` / `aptitude` as usual.